# connecting to a postgres database with sqlalchemy FATAL: password authentication failed for user

Tags: postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to setup a Postgres database and connect to it within my flask application. A quick test does seem to work

```
>>> import psycopg2
>>> conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='test_db' user='testuser' host='localhost' password='777'")
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> cur
<cursor object at 0x7ff36d8e49a0; closed: 0>
```

In my application I provide the same information to sqlalchemy via

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql+psycopg2://testuser:777@localhost/test_db'
```

but I get

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "testuser"
connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "testuser"
```

I can reproduce this error if I use the wrong password above

```
>>> import psycopg2
>>> conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='test_db' user='testuser' host='localhost' password='778'")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "testuser"
connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "testuser"
```

my /etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_hba.conf looks like this

```
local   all             postgres                                md5

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     all                                     peer
#host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
#host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

and here is the status of my postgres server

```
# sudo systemctl status PostgreSQL
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Sat 2023-09-02 18:37:30 UTC; 1h 31min ago
    Process: 41816 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 41816 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 2ms

Sep 02 18:37:30 benty-fields3 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Sep 02 18:37:30 benty-fields3 systemd[1]: Finished PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

and here is the list of users

```
postgres=# \du
                               List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes               | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 testuser | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

Following the tip by John in the comments I tested the permissions

```
test_db=# SELECT usename, usecreatedb, usesuper FROM pg_user;
  usename  | usecreatedb | usesuper 
-----------+-------------+----------
 postgres  | t           | t
 testuser | t           | t
(2 rows)
```

and here is the sqlalchemy version I have

```
# pip show sqlalchemy
Name: SQLAlchemy
Version: 2.0.20
```

and I have made testuser the owner of the database test_db

```
\l
                               List of databases
   Name    |   Owner   | Encoding | Collate |  Ctype  |    
Access privileges    
-----------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+-------------------------
 test_db  | testuser | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =Tc/testuser          + 
testuser=CTc/testuser
```

Comment: You should check if `testuser` has the required permission to connect to the`testdb` database by running `SELECT usename, usecreatedb, usesuper FROM pg_user;
` on the `testdb` database.

Comment: thanks @Nnaemeka Daniel John... I added this test above